# How to send a HTTP request and get the HTTP Response

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I want to send a HTTP request to http://YourWebSite.com/MessagefromMobiles.aspx and get the response.

And I want to send a response to the HTTP Get request I receive to http://MyWebSite.com/Hello.aspx page.

Can someone show me the correct way of doing this in C#?

**EDIT**

Please show me the correct direction rather than downvoting. If this is a very basic or silly question. Post something helpful and downvote.

Comment: @user1026857 You say you tried various things. It would worthwhile to mention what you tried. That helps people to show you the correct way

Comment: If you show us what you _tried_, we can accurately gauge where you are getting stuck and tailor an answer that will not only help you solve your problem, but also teach you something in the process. Not posting what you have tried basically short circuits one of the ultimate rewards of using Stack Overflow, which is walking away knowing a little bit more than you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HttpClient api](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) is much easier to use.  If you don't have [NuGet package manager](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) installed, get it, and install it. Once you've restarted visual studio, click on manage NuGet packages and search online for HttpClient.